# Why is this 3D shape deforming while playing the animation?

Tags: python, math, matrix

So I've got this python code and It was working fine until I tried to bring some perspective into the 3D shape, ever since the 3D shapes have been deforming. I can't figure out if this issue is a mathematical issue or a code based one, please someone I need a fresh set of eyes to help me out here. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import math
import time

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
triangle = [[90, 90, 0, 1], [180, 90, 0, 1], [180, 270, 0, 1], [120, 120, 80, 1]]
edgeTable = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]]

Matrix = [[1, 0, 0, 0] , [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

def Multiply(Matr, Vec):
    res = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            res[i]=res[i]+Matr[j][i]*Vec[j]
    return res

def MatMultiply(M1, M2):
    res = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(4):
        res[i] = Multiply(M1, M2[i])
    return res

def perspectiveMat():
    d = 1000
    PerspectiveMatRes = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1/d], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
    return PerspectiveMatRes

def RotZMat(angle):
    return [[math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle), 0, 0] , [-math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle), 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

def RotXMat(angle):
    return [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle), 0] , [0, -math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

def RotYMat(angle):
    return [[math.cos(angle), 0, math.sin(angle), 0],  [0, 1, 0, 0], [-math.sin(angle), 0, math.cos(angle), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

def CopyMat(Mat):
    res = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            res[i][j]=Mat[i][j]
    return res

def CopyVertices(Vert):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(Vert)):
        res[i]=[]
        for j in range(4):
            res[i][j]=Vert[i][j]
    return res

#angle = input(str("angle for x>> "))
angle = "1"
angle = int(angle)*math.pi/180

run = True
while run == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    rotM = RotXMat(angle)
    resMat = MatMultiply(perspectiveMat(), rotM)
    cloud = triangle.copy()
    for i in range(len(triangle)):
        cloud[i] = Multiply(resMat, triangle[i])

    screen.fill(white)
    for edge in edgeTable:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cloud[edge[0]][0]*cloud[edge[0]][3]+400, cloud[edge[0]][1]*cloud[edge[0]][3]+400),(cloud[edge[1]][0]*cloud[edge[1]][3]+400,cloud[edge[1]][1]*cloud[edge[1]][3]+400))
    angle = angle + math.pi/180
    time.sleep(0.04)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

`

I couldn't figure it out, I think it is a mathematical issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least two mathematical problems in your code. Plus one coding remark (not necessarily a problem). I start with this one, since it is necessary to be sure to speak the same language

0. Your matrix logic seems transposed compared to usual one (at least, usual in most libraries): you tread matrix as if they were an array of columns. Which, mathematically, makes sense. As we see in your own code for matrix multiplication: if a matrix is just an array of vectors/columns, then matrix `A=[Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]` multiplied by matrix `B=[Col1', Col2', Col3', Col4']` is just the array `[A@Col1', A@Col2', A@Col3', A@Col4']` (`@` being the matrix multiplication operator). This is what you do in your `MatMultiply` code.

It also shows in your `Multiply` code: a Matrix (Mᵢⱼ) times a vector (Vᵢ) is indeed the vector whose ith element is Σⱼ MᵢⱼVⱼ. Which is what you code, ... assuming that `Matr[j][i]` is what is mathematically noted Mᵢⱼ, that is the element at row i column j.

Usually, and especially in numpy (and with python operation `@`), we represent a matrix (Mᵢⱼ) as an array `Matr[i,j]` or `Matr[i][j]`, being the element at row i, and column j. In other words, a matrix is a array of rows, not an array of columns. So transposed from your representation. Again, that is just an implementation choice, but since yours is unusual, I need to be sure that we are ok

Now the two problems

1. Therefore, assuming that your perspective matrix was meant to be

```
/ 1    0    0     0   \
| 0    1    0     0   | 
| 0    0    1     0   |
\ 0    0    1/d   0   /
```

The problem is that 0 in the bottom right corner. Should be 1. Or at least something non-zero.

2. This is homogeneous coordinates, apparently. And habit is to interpret a vector `(x,y,z,a)` as `(x/a, y/a, z/a)`.
   Said otherwise vectors and matrix are all equivalent to a proportional factor. So `(x,y,z,a)` is the same as `(x/a, y/a, z/a, 1)`. And once we have a 1 as last coordinates, we can forget it for drawing.

Your code says otherwise. Your code says `(x,y,z,a) ~ (x*a, y*a, z*a)`, and, after projection on xy plane, `~ (x*a, y*a)`

That is not logic. Again, homogeneous coordinates are just one way to deal with perspective and projective operators. But it makes sense. With that `*a` it doesn't. It means that the closer the objects are, (the smaller z is) the smaller they appear. Usually, we think of perspective as something that shrinken distances for further objects.

Logic is to decide that eye is, over the scene (in the axis `z`, since you use axis x and y to draw) at a distance `d`. So `z=d`. Or `z=-d` (watching from the other side, which match more your existing code)
And therefore, projection on your eye, scale the sizes of things in the image by a factor proportional to the inverse of the distance between the eye and those things. If eye is at distance `z=-d`, then an object at `z=zₒ` is at a distance (along z axis, the one along which you'll project) `zₒ+d`.

Hence, what you want to draw on your 2d screen, is something at 2D coordinates
(x / (zₒ+d), y / (zₒ+d))
(If not convinced, just draw an example on a paper, and do the reasonning with Thales, no need for homogeneous coordinates : that is indeed what are the coordinates on the retina)

Homogeneous coordinates are just a way to write this non linear operation (transformation from point 3D (x,y,z) to 2D point (x/(z+d), y/(z+d)) is not a linear transform, in classical cartesian coordinates) using only linear operations.
Since, in homogeneous coordinates (x/(z+d), y/(z+d), 0, 1) is the same as `(x, y, 0, z+d)`

So, I got rid of the non-linear division. It is still apparently affine, not linear, because of the `+d`. But in homogeenous coordinates, thanks to the extra `1`, affine operations are just linear operation also.

From a vector `(x,y,z,1)`, that `(x,y,0,z+d)` can be obtained by matrix × vector multiplication

```
/   1   0   0   0   \   / x \
|   0   1   0   0   |   | y |
|   0   0   0   0   |   | z |
\   0   0   1   d   /   \ 1 /
```

Or, to get closer to your matrix (I always try to keep as close as possible to initial code), since after all, you just ignore the 3rd component afterward, (you never use `cloud[...][2]`), it doesn't matter if we get (x,y,z,z+d) instead of (x,y,0,z+d)  (it just means that we first perform the "perspective", then the projection), which is what you would get with multiplication

```
/  1   0   0   0  \  / x \
|  0   1   0   0  |  | y |
|  0   0   1   0  |  | z |
\  0   0   1   d  /  \ 1 /
```

With this matrix, you transform (x,y,z,1) into (X,Y,Z,A)=(x,y,z,x+d). Which is what you want to do, if you correctly then draw, into the 2d image plane, at coordinates `(X/A, Y/A)`, not `(X*A, Y*A)` — see 1st problem

There is still one remaining problem: exactly as a photographer can decide, when taking a picture of an object, to take a picture from a close distance, or from a further distance, but with a zoom, you need to correct the global zoom of your image to take into account the distance. Otherwise, the bigger `d` parameter is, the smaller your whole drawing will be. And I guess that what you wanted is the control the perspective with parameter `d` (how further object are shrinked compared to closer one), but not the global size.

One way it to zoom everything by a factor d

That is to draw `(d×x/(z+d), d×y(z+d))`

Which you can get by mutiplying x and y (and, indifferently, z) by `d`, hence replacing the previous matrix by

```
/  d   0   0   0  \
|  0   d   0   0  |
|  0   0   d   0  |
\  0   0   1   d  /
```

But since, with homogeneous coordinates, matrix and vector are equivalent after a proportional factor, that is the same as matrix

```
/  1   0   0   0 \
|  0   1   0   0 |
|  0   0   1   0 |
\  0   0   1/d 1 /
```

Which is almost your initial matrix.

Hence the minimal correction to your code:

- Add a 1 as the bottom right element of your perspective matrix
- Replace drawing code
  `pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cloud[edge[0]][0]*cloud[edge[0]][3]+400, cloud[edge[0]][1]*cloud[edge[0]][3]+400),(cloud[edge[1]][0]*cloud[edge[1]][3]+400,cloud[edge[1]][1]*cloud[edge[1]][3]+400)`
  by
  `pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (cloud[edge[0]][0]/cloud[edge[0]][3]+400, cloud[edge[0]][1]/cloud[edge[0]][3]+400),(cloud[edge[1]][0]/cloud[edge[1]][3]+400,cloud[edge[1]][1]/cloud[edge[1]][3]+400)`

With those two modifications, you get a code that is simulating what you would get if you take an image with a camera from a distance `d`, with a compensating zoom `d`

## Edit

That was not asked for, but I can't resist the urge to rewrite in numpy

```py
import pygame
import math
import time
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
triangle = np.array([[90.0, 90, 0, 1], [180, 90, 0, 1], [180, 270, 0, 1], [120, 120, 80, 1]]).T
edgeTable = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]]

def perspectiveMat(d):
    return np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1/d, 1]])

def RotZMat(angle):
    return np.array([[np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle), 0, 0] , [-np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle), 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

def RotXMat(angle):
    return np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle), 0] , [0, -np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

def RotYMat(angle):
    return np.array([[np.cos(angle), 0, np.sin(angle), 0],  [0, 1, 0, 0], [-np.sin(angle), 0, np.cos(angle), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

angle = np.pi/180

run = True
while run == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    rotM = RotXMat(angle)
    resMat = perspectiveMat(1000) @ rotM
    cloud = resMat @ triangle

    screen.fill(white)
    for edge in edgeTable:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, black, cloud[:2,edge[0]]/cloud[3,edge[0]]+[400,400], cloud[:2,edge[1]]/cloud[3,edge[1]]+[400,400]) 
    angle = angle + np.pi/180
    time.sleep(0.04)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

You can see that using numpy, I can drop the two mutliplication (matrix × vector and matrix × matrix) since they are just obtained by `@`).
No need for copy functions neither (we can get a copy with method `.copy()`, but here, we don't really need it, since matrix product creates a new result anyway).

I have also removed your identity `Matrix` since you don't use it. But if I wanted to keep it, that would be just `Matrix=np.identity(4)`.

And finally, the computation of the coordinates to draw is also simplified: for example
`cloud[:2,edge[0]]/cloud[3,edge[0]]+[400,400]`
means `2 first rows of column` edge[0]`of`cloud`, divided by last row of column` edge[0]`of`cloud`. Which is a pair (since I do the same operation on the 2 first rows). To which I add the pair` [400,400]`.